# Nginx Redirect with variable Haders

Tags: nginx

I'm completly new to nginx but someone told me that it is the way to go with my problem.

Imagine I have the following url: `<customer>.sub.domain.net`.
I now want to redirect all of that traffic to `anotherdomain.net` but with an special Header that has the content of `<customer>` from the request URL.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is <customer> a variable?

Comment: @Larry.He It's not a fixed value.